# powerofTwo algorithm solution

Tags: javascript

Below is my algo to check if number is a power of two. When I run this algo in test case "2" the answer is false. I want to know why it behaves this way ?

```
  var isPowerOfTwo = function(n) {
      if(n === 1){
         console.log("i came here");
         return true;     
      }
      if(n === 0){
         return false;   
      }
      if(n%2 === 0){
         console.log(n);
         n=n/2;
         console.log(n);
         isPowerOfTwo(n);   
      }   
      if(n%2 === 1){
         return false;   
      }
 };
```

Comment: recursion is for newbies :p `const isPowerOfTwo = n => n.toString(1).split('1').length === 2`

Comment: @JaromandaX Should be `toString(2)` as "radix" can't be 1 ... and it is not fool proof, as passing the string `'1'` gives `true` (which is ok), but `'2'` give `false` (which then is not ok), so either all strings should fail, or any number as a `string` produce the same result a number as a `number` does

Comment: @JaromandaX E.g. `const isPowerOfTwo = n => typeof n === 'number' && n.toString(2).split('1').length === 2` ... or `const isPowerOfTwo = n => Number(n).toString(2).split('1').length === 2`

Comment: @JaromandaX It is still an interesting solution so if I were you I'd post it :)

Comment: sorry, typo, yes `toString(2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not `return`ing the recursive call, and you're also changing `n` before the tests have finished - if `n / 2` resolves to `1` then your reassignment of `n` will result in the bottom `if` statement running. Use `else` instead, and don't reassign `n`, simply pass `n / 2` to the recursive call:

```js
var isPowerOfTwo = function(n) {
  if (n === 1) return true;
  if (n === 0) return false;
  if (n % 2 === 0) return isPowerOfTwo(n / 2);
  else return false;
};
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(2));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(8));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(6));
```

Your `if (n%2 === 1) return false;` condition could result in another bug: what if the initial `n` was not an integer? Then the function would call itself forever, resulting in an overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Because 1 % 2 === 1
The "problem" is that in the third if you are changing the value of n and not returning any value so it will enter the last if too.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you don't return any value in the 3rd `if` statement, hence you always get `false` for values greater than 1 as it will execute the 4th statement too.

In addition to the given answers, here is an interesting solution (initially by [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810303/poweroftwo-algorithm-solution/50815353#comment88626835_50810303)), which I expanded so it deals with if a non-number is passed as a value.

Try cast to a number

```js
const isPowerOfTwo = n => Number(n).toString(2).split('1').length === 2

console.log(isPowerOfTwo(''));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo('0'));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo('1'));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo('2'));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(2));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(8));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(6));
```

Check the type

```js
const isPowerOfTwo = n => typeof n === 'number' && n.toString(2).split('1').length === 2

console.log(isPowerOfTwo(''));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo('0'));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo('1'));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo('2'));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(2));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(8));
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(6));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to return an actual value from the `n % 2 === 0` branch of your function:

```
var isPowerOfTwo = function(n) {
    if (n === 1) {
        console.log("i came here");
        return true;     
    }
    else if (n === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (n % 2 === 0) {
        console.log(n);
        n = n / 2;
        console.log(n);
        return isPowerOfTwo(n);   
    }   
    else {   // no need for an if here
        return false;   
    }
};
```

Note that in the final `else` we do not need to check anything, because we have already ascertained the number is not a multiple of `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript one-liner solution

For any power of 2 (n & n - 1) will return 0. Simple bit-wise operators

```
isPowerOfTwo = n => !(n & n - 1)
```

The above function will return true for 0, which is not a power of 2. For that

```
isPowerOfTwo = n => (n != 0) && !(n & n - 1)
```